# Send-MailMessage - Multiple Recepients - Combine Text and Variables

Tags: string, powershell

I am trying to compose a multi-recipient address. But I cannot combine string email addresses and email address from a variable:

```
$ManagerEmail = Get-ADUser -Identity $TemplateUser -Properties Manager | Select-Object @{Name="ManagerEmail";Expression={(get-aduser -property emailaddress $_.manager).emailaddress}}
$MailCc = "helpdesk@abc.com","hr@abc.com" + "," + $ManagerEmail
```

Error:

```
Send-MailMessage : An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','.
```

How do I add the $ManagerEmail? (Note that the $ManagerEmail is correctly getting the email i.e. hismanager@abc.com.)

I am expecting to send the email with the Manager cc'd.

Comment: `$MailCc = "helpdesk@abc.com","hr@abc.com",$ManagerEmail.ManagerEmail`

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasR.Jessen, it is working now,  Nelson

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are delimited by a `,` sign. E.g. `"a","b",0..2`.

In your example you are using `","` which would make the object a string instead of an array.

[See this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3) about arrays in PowerShell.

The complete code would thus be:

```
$ManagerEmail = (Get-ADUser -Identity $TemplateUser -Properties Manager `
| Select-Object @{Name="ManagerEmail"; `
Expression={(get-aduser -property emailaddress $_.manager).emailaddress}}).ManagerEmail
$MailCc = "helpdesk@abc.com","hr@abc.com",$ManagerEmail
```

Comment: The preceding expression creates an object with a `ManagerEmail` property, so `...,$ManagerEmail` is gonna expand to `@{ManagerEmail=email@address.example}` when converted to a string

Comment: Correct, I didn't check the code from the question poster since he mentioned that it worked. Edited that piece of script. Thx!